# Running 5 Spring boot application as standalone vs Deploying all in one Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Am having 5 Spring boot applications and I have to run them in a single machine.

Which is the most efficient way to run these

1. Running all the micro services separately as different micro services
2. Deploy all together in tomcat cat server as WAR

I dont have any special requirement. I just want to know which is efficient in terms of Memory, I/O , Processing, Latency, Scalability

Comment: this is highly opinionated. if it is about memory -> war (a bit), i/o, processing, latency-> does not matter, scalability -> micro; startup/redeploy time, fault tollerance/isolation -> micro

Comment: u mean running 5 micro services is same as deploying all in Tomcat?

Comment: as I understand your case - you have 5 apps and now you are asking if to run it as 5xjava or as 5xwar in one tomcat. and when we "compare" e.g. I/O as a result of DB queries, those 5 application will do some DB queries regardless if they run as standalone java (with embedded tomcat) or within one tomcat server.... therefore I don't see any significant difference.

Answer (score -1):

For example, in case when one of your apps fails you should restart only this one with Spring Boot. Otherwise, you should restart entire Tomcat server with all apps installed.

Another things are processing and scalability: if you have separated modules which are independent for each other (apps in your case), it's always simpler to maintain and modify them with no affect to another one (see item #1).

In terms of memory, I/O and latency see item #1 - it's always easier to have a deal with one separated app than with large number of them at once. :)

So if your apps are loosely coupled (by functionality, for example) your case may be a Spring Boot, otherwise you can use Tomcat server.

Comment: What do you mean by one app fails? And why cant I do hot deployment. Please explain your "loosely coupled, spring boot and tomcat server".. what is the relationship between all these here...

Comment: App fails => it means here that app needs to be redeployed (it isn't always a Tomcat server is started with "autoDeploy" attribute 'true' :(

Comment: Loosely coupled in this case means that all of your 5 apps don't solve the same one **big** problem and have different purposes at all. If it is, you can use Spring Boot, as for me.

Comment: One more question: Are you going to deploy all your apps as one WAR or different WAR's for each application?

Comment: In the first case, I think you should read again what I wrote before ;) In the second case, I guess choice is obvious in favor of Spring Boot (because it's more convenient and doesn't need extra steps when deploying and just start of app).

Comment: 1. What is autodeploy true? Where do add it? How does not tomcat do auto redeploy by itself?
2. Loosely coupled?? Loosely coupling does not mean that  they cannot one big problem, please dont give pointless answers
3. Please guide me in deploying 5 different spring boot apps in one single war. 
4. What is the extra step u need when u deploy a non spring boot application